# How to delete queue from hangfire?

Tags: sql-delete, jobs, hangfire

Can someone help me to figure out how to **delete the queue from an enqueued job in Hangfire**? I deleted all the jobs from the queue but the queues are still there. I found a way to achieve this by deleting the table from the database but this is not an effective way.
[hangfire](/questions/tagged/hangfire)[queue](/questions/tagged/queue)[delete](/questions/tagged/delete)[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5GAt.png)

I deleted all jobs in enqueued jobs in hangfire but queues are still showing there,
I want to delete all the queues from enqueued job.